# Gitlab repositories disappeared

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, project

I have lost access to all my projects (since Friday, July 22) created under a group that suddenly disappeared without any action.
Now all my projects' path doesn’t work (404 project doesn’t exist)

Can you tell me if there is any way to recover them please ?
I contacted the support but they didn’t answer me yet.

Comment: It happened to me, too. 
Did you solve at the end? How?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately Gitlab support told me that one of my team members has deleted the group where all projects was created and there is no way to restore them since I am a free Gitlab user.

Answer (score 0):

404 should mean you are not properly logged-in/authenticate to gitlab.com (assuming you are talking about the SaaS gitlab.com service)

Make sure first your account is accessible, before checking for your project URLs.

Comment: There is no problem with my account access because i can see all other projects created under other groups except one group that disappeared suddenly with all projects

Comment: So it is like the group visibility itself had changed. Only GitLab support would be able to investigate in that case.

Comment: Ok, so i have to wait to the answear from gitlab support, Thanks